# retrieving image from remote mysql db to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, http

how to fetch the image stored in mysql on server? I want to fetch those images based on the values user has entered (means dynamic query). I want to use json to send the image from php to android. I successfully displayed that image in web browser using static query but when I saw the response of the php in android app it shows some html code instead of image.please help me in parsing the image json response and displaying that image.
following is the php code to send image to android.

```
 while($post = mysql_fetch_object($data))
 {
    $posts[] = $post;

 }
         //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

         echo '{"pprs":'.json_encode($posts).'}';
```

now i am getting response : {"pprs":[{"pprs":null},{"pprs":null}]}

please help me.Thank you.

Comment: you have to show the response in order for us to parse it.

Comment: Do you have any sample code or anything? Without any more details, it's very difficult as to what may be happening.

Comment: I am getting the following response 2{"pprs":null}{"pprs":null}

Comment: 2 are the number of rows fetched from db but it shows null.

Comment: currently i am trying static sql query to retrieve all the images from mysql. As shown in the code above $data contains query result.

Comment: In android I am getting following response :  org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40561730

Comment: The easiest way of debugging issues like your would be (IMHO) to use Wireshark to sniff on your WiFi router your android phone is connected to. Then find a part of the HTTP connection (packet) and make wireshark find all parts. This will give you a nice understandable HTTP session where you should be able to see what client and server are sending/receiving.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your image to string if you want to use JSON:

```
    $posts[] = base64_encode($post);
```

And on Android side:

```
String base64image = jsonobject.getString("pprs");
byte[] rawImage = Base64.decode(base64image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length);
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPicture);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```